# Swift: how to change default behaviour of buttons "Use Photo", "Cancel", "Shoot", "Retake" of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770160/swift-pause-cmmotionmanager-while-deciding-if-to-keep-the-photo) I would need to modify a little the actions/behaviour of the buttons listed in titled. I would like to avoid to build a new image picker overlay as some posts suggest. I just need to add a call to one of my methods into default actions. Isn't there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

As explained in the [UIImagePickerController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/):

> The `UIImagePickerController` class manages customizable,
>   system-supplied user interfaces for taking pictures and movies on
>   supported devices, and for choosing saved images and movies for use in
>   your app. An image picker controller manages user interactions and
>   delivers the results of those interactions to a delegate object.

And then:

> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the AV
>   Foundation framework as described in [Media Capture and Access to
>   Camera](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW10).

Comment: Thank you...avevo iniziato a temere che fosse così. What about this tutorial instead: http://makeapppie.com/tag/cameraoverlayview/? maybe it could be easier than AV Foundation about which I know nothing :(